# TableLayout goes behind Navigation bar

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, navigationbar

i am having a problem with the TableLayout which is going behind the NavigationBar as you see :

[image: All rows are given a weight of 1, as you see thursday row is smaller meaning it goes behind NavBar]

The two tabs have a viewPager which contains the fragment layout (TableLayout):

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<TableRow
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="/"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="8-9"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="9-10"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="10-11"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="11-12"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    >
    <TextView android:text="Sunday"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
    <TextView android:text="Monday"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    >
    <TextView android:text="Tuesday"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView android:text="Wednesday"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    >
    <TextView android:text="Thursday"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
</TableRow>
```

And this is the viewPager:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute in your `<CoordinatorLayout/>`

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```